# How to add digital signature or signature image in PDF using python/django?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I am trying to insert an signature image in a contract pdf like the way we do in adobe acrobat in offline.I tried to install a 3rd party package `signpdf 0.0.3` but it seems not maintained anymore and not working in python 3.6 and django 2.0. Is there any way i can achieve the desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) to generate a new pdf file and use this file a water mark over the old pdf file.

Comment: Hi Veenu! It would be good to add also some code example instead of plain link.